# ArrayList remove more than 1 per for loop?

Tags: java

```
for(PatientProcedures s: PatientProceduresList)
        {

            if(Num == s.getAccountNumber())
            {
                PatientProceduresList.remove(s);
                break;
                //without break it stops cause of loop 


            }
        }
```

Is there anyway around this? It works with the break but I need to continue and keep doing the same thing to the rest of the arraylist.

Comment: If you remove the `break;`, it will remove any values of s that match Num.

Comment: If he removes the break, then it will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: You cannot remove from array list while traversing it unless you're using an iterator. Check javadocs for additional information.

Comment: dont modify the wheels while driving!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do this, you must use the [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

```
Iterator<PatientProcedures> iterator = list.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext())
{
    PatientProcedures s = iterator.next();

    if (wantToRemove)
    {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

This will avoid the `ConcurrentModificationException` that exists when you do a `for` each loop.